# Retain email subject when sending mail merge via Publisher 2010?

Tags: email, microsoft-office-2010, mail-merge, microsoft-publisher

I am using Publisher 2010 to send a mail merge via email.  I choose "Finish & Merge" and then "Send Email Messages..." and finally, after entering a Subject, hit "Send."  No problem!

The **expected behavior** is that the next time I send a mail merge, it will use the same subject line as last time.

The **reality** is that when I go to "Send Email Messages..." the Subject field is blank.

Am I missing something?  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just updating.  I still have not been able to find a solution for this...

Comment: I've been encountering other small issues like this -- for example, Publisher 2010 will only send the last of multiple attachments, rather than all of them (a bug that's existed since Publisher 2007).  I think this may just be another bug Microsoft never felt important enough to fix...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time, it looks like this is simply a bug that Microsoft does not intend to fix.  Sad...

The only workaround I have found is to copy in the desired subject from another source every time I send it.  It's an extra step, but better than a blank subject!

Comment: Just a minor update. I recently had the opportunity to upgrade to Office 2013, and frustratingly this behavior remains in Publisher 2013. It's kind of embarrassing!